# Calculate x1 x2 y1 y2 from center coordinates,height and width

Tags: math, coordinates

What i have here is a rectangle or square.I have the center coordinates,width and height.How do i go about finding the x1,x2,y1 and y3 from these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be lots of different answers, because you can rotate the rectangle about the center and get different values for the corners.

But, if I assume you mean the usual orientation with sides parallel to the x- and y-axis, it seems right that you'd alternate adding and subtracting half the width and height from the center to obtain the corner coordinates.

Comment: No one needs you to tell us that this is the "easy" solution.  I alluded to the trig with the orientation comments.  I don't think this poor question deserves more.  Nothing but a useless "me too" comment from you.  Why bother?